# Beer ad in The Matrix

Tags: the-matrix

I'm curious about a little detail in *The Matrix* movie: at the subway station, where Neo fights Smith, there's an ad in a wall: *"Sol"*.

[image]

I know it's quite irrelevant, but it's the logo of a Mexican beer ("Cerveza Sol")... is there any explanation about why it was included?

Comment: http://www.matrixfans.net/symbolism-philosophy-and-allegory/little-details-references/ - seems to be the consensus analysis from the few sites I saw - nothing 'word of god' from producers, etc.. though that I can see

Comment: Maybe they were filming in a subway station, and there were preexisting advertisements or graffiti.

Comment: It was just a little glitch of the reality rendering by the Matrix.

Comment: Neo is drinking a Sol beer in the nightclub when he first meets Trinity also.![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UDNQ.jpg)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Theory #1

It was a product placement. Note that the scene also includes a Pepsi Cola placement.

[image: A still from the film The Matrix, showing a Pepsi Cola vending machine in the background. The characters in the foreground are blurry due to motion.]

As well as a "blink and you'll miss it" ad for Hewlett Packard.

[image: A still from the film The Matrix, showing a black booted foot on a subway platform, while another man is standing on the tracks. The camera is at his eye level. Behind him, on the wall, is a faded and graffitied over advertising poster for HP.]

### Theory #2

It was a sly reference to another Keanu Movie; *Johnny Mnemonic* in which the titular Johnny, played by Reeves, states his fond desire for a

> "cold Mexican beer"

Comment: Could it have just been coincidence? Were they filming on a set or in a real subway station?

Comment: @Adamant - It was filmed in a "train storage yard" rather than a real railway station (or even an abandoned one). As such there would have been no wall-adverts.

Comment: Wow! Indeed I missed the HP as!

Comment: “Johnny Mnemonic” — the movie the Matrix could have been!

Comment: @PaulDWaite - The movie The Matrix wishes it was...

Comment: If Keanu Reeves wanted cold Mexican beer, Sol wouldn't be the one I'd recommend :P

Comment: @Barranka Also if he wanted a cola, Pepsi wouldn't be the one I'd recommend. And if he wanted a laptop, HP wouldn't be the one I'd recommend. And if he wanted a good sci fi movie, The Matrix wouldn't be the one I'd recommend.

Comment: @MishaR: Oooooh! Saucer of milk? Table 2